# XSLT: select element by another element's value

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I output value of one element which depends on anothers element value ? 
I want to use another element's value in place of XXX

```
<xsl:value-of select="/node1/node2[@name=XXX]"/@lng>
```

and in XXX place I want value of:

```
/node3/node4/@val
```

simplified xml:

```
<node>
    <node1>
        <node2 name="abc" lng="uk">
        </node2>
    </node1>
    <node3>
        <node4 val="abc">
        </node4>
    </node3>
</node>
```

I know it can be achieved by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/node1/node2[@name='abc']"/@lng>
```

but I don't know what value will be in node4/@val
How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

One answer to your question would be to do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="/node/node1/node2[@name=/node/node3/node4/@val]/@lng" />
```

Or slightly better, to use a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="node4val" select="/node/node3/node4/@val" />
<xsl:value-of select="/node/node1/node2[@name=$node4val]/@lng" />
```

But I am guessing you may have multiple `node4` elements in your XML, and perhaps you want to get the value for each one? In this case, it would look more like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node/node3/node4">
   <xsl:value-of select="/node/node1/node2[@name=current()/@val]/@lng" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or, with a variable

```
<xsl:for-each select="/node/node3/node4">
   <xsl:variable name="val" select="@val" />
   <xsl:value-of select="/node/node1/node2[@name=$val]/@lng" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Better still would be to use a key. Try this, for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="node2s" match="node2" use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/node/node3/node4">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('node2s', @val)/@lng" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```